# Need to sort dynamic array of pointers to structs with possible NULL pointers among them

Tags: c, pointers, struct, qsort

I'm trying to figure out how to sort an array of pointers to structures with possible null pointers among them. But I cannot get my head around it and keep getting crashes right after the sort.

I have two structures, `CAR` and `CARLIST`: 
`CARLIST` has an array of pointers to `CARS`. And I just cant get it right.

THANKS for any help...

```
typedef struct Car {
    int parked_Total_Minutes;
    char rz[10];
} CAR;

typedef struct CarList {
    CAR **p_cars;
    unsigned int count;
    unsigned int size;
} CARLIST;

int Compare_ParkedTime(const void *a, const void *b) {
     if (a == NULL)
          return -1;

     if (b == NULL)
          return 1;

     CAR *aa = *(CAR* const *)a;
     CAR *bb = *(CAR* const *)b;

     return  (bb->parked_Total_Minutes < aa->parked_Total_Minutes) - (aa->parked_Total_Minutes < bb->parked_Total_Minutes);
}

int main() {
    ....
    CARLIST *p_AllCars = (CARLIST *)malloc(sizeof(CARLIST));
    p_AllCars->count = 0;
    p_AllCars->size = 10;
    p_AllCars->p_cars = malloc(p_AllCars->size * sizeof(CAR *));

    for(int i = 0; i < p_AllCars->size; i++)
         p_AllCars->p_cars[i] = NULL;

    ... other logic generating cars ...

    qsort((void*)p_AllCars->p_cars, p_AllCars->size, sizeof(CAR*), Compare_ParkedTime);

    ...
}
```

Comment: What is the reason you allocate the `CARLIST` structure dynamically?

Comment: In `Compare_ParkedTime` , `a` and `b` cannot be NULL, they *point to* your array elements. `aa` and `bb` *are* your array elements, and they *can be* NULL.

Comment: No real reason....

Comment: As for your problem, can you please elaborate on it? What happens when you run the code? If you enable verbose warnings when building, do the compiler emit any warnings for your code?

Comment: n.m. > changed the check, im still getting the crash on sort.

Comment: Some programmer dude > im on windows in Clion right now, no Linux around. But without the sort everything runs smoothly.

Comment: If the compare function is invoked with two values, `a` and `b`, then if `Compare_ParkedTime(a, b)` returns `-1` (shorthand for 'negative value'), it is required that `Compare_ParkedTime(b, a)` returns `+1`, and vice versa. If `a` and `b` are both null pointers, your function doesn't do that. Whether that actually causes trouble for you isn't clear, but it's a good rule to remember. You say "crashes right after the sort" — does that mean that the sort completes, but the code using the sorted array crashes? Is the sort preserving the input data — are the pointers before and after the same?

Comment: I don't see any changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comparison function gets pointers inside the array to be sorted. You should first read the pointers from this array and then test for `NULL`.

You should return 0 if both pointers are `NULL` and probably make null pointers larger than other values.

Here is a corrected version of the comparison function:

```
int Compare_ParkedTime(const void *a, const void *b) {
    /* read the pointer values */
    CAR *aa = *(CAR * const *)a;
    CAR *bb = *(CAR * const *)b;

    /* sort NULL pointers to the end of the array */
    if (aa == NULL)
        return (bb != NULL);
    if (bb == NULL)
        return -1;

    /* sort by increasing value of parked_Total_Minutes. swap aa and bb for decreasing order */
    return (bb->parked_Total_Minutes < aa->parked_Total_Minutes) -
           (aa->parked_Total_Minutes < bb->parked_Total_Minutes);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If the validity of the passed pointers is checked inside the comparison function, those checks are performed every time this function is executed while sorting. Any pointer could be tested multiple times for the same condition.

If instead the array is "sanitized" before sorting, by moving all the NULLs at the end:

```
size_t remove_nulls(CAR **cars, size_t n)
{
    // Find the first NULL (thanks again, @chqrlie)
    size_t count = 0;
    while(count < n && cars[count])
    {
        ++count;
    }

    // Move the elements to 'fill' the blanks
    for (size_t i = count; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if ( cars[i] )
        {
            cars[count] = cars[i];
            ++count;
        }
    }

    // The last pointers must be overwritten
    for (size_t i = count; i < n; ++i)
        cars[i] = NULL;

    // Returns the number of valid pointers
    return count;
}
```

Then, as [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) pointed out, you can remove the NULL checks from the comparison function and sort only the valid pointers.

Comment: @DavidWaldo Please note that if moving too many elements of the source array is a concern bigger than shuffling it a little bit more (my posted algorithm is stable, but you have to sort anyways...), you could use [this version](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2S5mgnoCRl8UxwOU) which, instead of moving all the elements to fill the blanks, just swap the last valid pointer with the NULL one.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to you ALL!!!
I was finally able to create the sort from your answers. 
Big thanks to n.m and Jonathan Leffler.

The sort looks like this...

```
int Compare_ParkedTime( const void* a, const void* b ){
    CAR *aa = *(CAR* const *)a;
    CAR *bb = *(CAR* const *)b;


    if (aa == NULL && bb == NULL)return 0;
    if (aa == NULL)return 1;
    if (bb == NULL)return  -1;

    return  (aa->parked_Total_Minutes < bb->parked_Total_Minutes) - (bb->parked_Total_Minutes < aa->parked_Total_Minutes);
}
```